# How do I enable high level SIL optimizations for containers in a non-stdlib Swift framework?

Tags: swift, optimization, inline, compiler-optimization

Having read [High level SIL optimizations](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/HighLevelSILOptimizations.rst), I took special note of the following (under
**Cloning code from the standard library**):

> The Swift compiler can copy code from the standard library into the
> application. This allows the optimizer to inline calls from stdlib and
> improve the performance of code that uses common operators such as
> '++' or basic containers such as Array. However, importing code from
> the standard library can increase the binary size. Marking functions
> with @_semantics("stdlib_binary_only") will prevent the copying of the
> marked function from the standard library into the user program.

Now, this is great and all. But, what if I'm writing my own containers?

I'm currently writing a framework that (philosophically) extends the standard library, introducing what I feel are some lacking data structures; such as trees and graphs.

However, from what I understand, these containers will (outside my framework) **not** be given the special cloning/inlining treatment, even if they are tediously marked with the relevant `@effects`, `@inline(__always)` or `@_transparent` etc. attributes. These optimizations, as I understand them, **are exclusive to only the standard library and friends**.

The optimizations, if any, will only be applied to code **within** my framework, and not modules that **import** my framework.

This makes things very difficult for me. What it effectively means is that, to leverage the power of these high level optimizations, **all my code must be in one module**. That is simply not possible.

I have about ~800 dense, Swift files spanning across 9 frameworks. The compilation time alone would be a nightmare; not to mention how badly it would traumatize `SourceKitService` (and me, for that matter).

How do I work around this, if at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cross-module-inlining](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0193-cross-module-inlining-and-specialization.md) is now available for Swift 4.2 and above!